# Manage permissions for quintagroup seoptimizer

Tags: seo, plone

I have added the [SEOptimizer](https://plone.org/products/plone-seo) add-on to my site, and need to restrict who can access the SEO tab. I'm not sure how to manage permissions for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default add-on permission use the "`Modify portal content`" permission, so users able to edit the content will see the tab: https://github.com/quintagroup/quintagroup.seoptimizer/blob/5d0ee147f2b094ea8a05849f1d77161a8329bb44/quintagroup/seoptimizer/profiles/default/actions.xml#L14

You can change this behavior by changing the permission related to this action **and** the `permission` in the ZCML: https://github.com/quintagroup/quintagroup.seoptimizer/blob/f55624284a7daa6c225801990e6b2e9801b9eeac/quintagroup/seoptimizer/browser/configure.zcml#L95

Change the permission used by the action is simple (you can do it also TTW accessing ZMI and `portal_action` tool).

Changing the ZCML permission needs a registration of a new ZCML that will override the old registration: See http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/zcml.html#overrides

You probably need to register a new permission, to be given to your "SEO" role.

BTW: this can be a really good change for the original product too: think about open an [issue](https://github.com/quintagroup/quintagroup.seoptimizer/issues).